# Nginx default content-type

Tags: nginx, content-type

I would like NGINX send the content-type application/xml
for all response of a location:

My configuration is base on the documentation http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#types :

```
 server {

      server_name my_name
      listen 8088;
      keepalive_timeout 5;

      location / { 
        proxy_pass http://myhost;

        types         { } 
        default_type  application/xml
     }   
   }
```

But the server always send as content-type "text/xml".
Any idea?

Comment: if your url ends with ".xml" try forcing the `application/xml` for xml type inside types `types { xml application/xml; }`

Comment: Silly question, but are you missing a semicolon in configuration after `default_type` line?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady but that time it forces to download instead of displaying it